# Why Julia is printing junk data to the file?

Tags: file, julia

I am new to Julia & this may be a really silly question :) I am running a calculation in Julia & want to output the result to a text file. The main program contains a for loop. After each loop, a single line containing the result for that iteration should be added in the output file(append ). Each line contains multiple values & they should be separated by space.

I checked Julia documentation & syntax seemed quite similar to C++. I have tested that with the following code.

```
using Distributions
f = open("hello.txt","w")
write(f,"Hello again.")
close(f)

numbers=rand(5)

f = open("hello.txt","a")
write(f,numbers)
close(f)

f = open("hello.txt","a")
numbers=rand(5)
print(numbers)

write(f,numbers)

close(f)
```

Here, I am writing random numbers to a file preceded by a general hello statement. But the output file looks like this though the numbers array contain float numbers (verified in console output).

```
Hello again.�7D����?L'Uf���?8��f��?���>��?����XX�?�x�m��?Y�]���?�v�S���?x���]�?�zPLΠ�?
```

Surely, I am doing something silly. This issue is never reported before.
I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

And as a good practice, should we need to put close(f)/flush(f) after appending each line(in case of appending data through for loop ) or using close(f) at the end of operation suffice?

Thank you in advance.
(Julia 1.6 , Linux 64 bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation of `write`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.write):

> Write the canonical binary representation of a value to the given I/O stream or file.

It looks like you want "text representation" of the numbers, and then you should use [`print`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.print). For `String`s, however, the binary representation is the same, so that is why `write` works with the string.

```
julia> open("file.txt", "w") do io
           println(io, "Hello")
           println(io, rand(3))
       end

shell> cat file.txt
Hello
[0.11312836652899494, 0.22752036377169926, 0.04622217336925327]
```

> should we need to put close(f)/flush(f) after appending each line(in case of appending data through for loop ) or using close(f) at the end of operation suffice?

The stream is `flush`ed on `close`.

Comment: Thank you. Just a small question. If 'write' is supposed to put the binary representation then why the file shows those characters instead of the binary stream?

Comment: Is it specific to gedit?

Comment: The editor probably assumes/guesses that it is a text file (e.g. with for example UTF-8 encoding) and tries to display the data in the file as characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Delimited files module](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/#Delimited-Files) with the `writedlm` function:

```
using DelimitedFiles

julia> open("hello.txt", "a") do io
            writedlm(io, numbers)
       end
```

but this seems to be specific for writing numbers from my understanding.